# Bash countdown to execution if no key pressed

Tags: linux, bash

I've seen this a bunch of times in bash programs.  I need to start a timer that can be cancelled on key press.  If no key is pressed it will execute a command.  Using it for automated vagrant config.

What I want to see in the terminal:

```
Automatically installing in (10) ## this number should count down
Press any key to cancel automatic install.
```

Comment: Updating the count in-place is the trickiest part of doing this (assuming you don't want to just clear the screen each update). Other than that this is likely just a `read` with a timeout in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `read` for that with time-out option:

```
read -n 1 -t 10
```

This will wait 10 seconds for single char. If key was pressed return value will be `0`:

```
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    # key was pressed
    exit
fi
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks!